# Heavily templated mathematical vector class

Tags: c++, template, coordinate-system

I started to write a library for linear algebra for personal use, but also for revitilization of my C++.

Below is the first class of this library, a templated vector class, which is templated over the type of the elements as well as the size. It supports all common operations of vectors as member functions and also as static functions, to support different coding preferences. I also overloaded the operators, that make sense in my opinion. I templated over the size because I need the byte-size of a float vector to be 4*n.

Generally all suggestions and comments are more than welcome, but I also have a few points I specifically want to ask about:

- **Interface-Design**: Choice of providing both non-static and static versions of most operations, and implementing operators in terms of the static functions
- **Inlining**: Did I miss functions, that can be inlined without further thought? Should I remove inlining from some functions
- **Functionality**: Did I miss functions/operators that the class should have?
- **Function naming**: I'm not completely satisfied with some namen, but can't think of better ones, that are still exact. Maybe someone has suggestions?

**Thanks for your time!**

---

```
template<typename T, uint32_t size>
class Vector {
private:
    std::array<T, size> data;

public:
    Vector() : Vector<T, size>(T(0)) {}

    Vector(T value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] = value;
        }
    }

    Vector(std::array<T, size> data) {
        this->data = data;
    }

public:
    Vector<T, size>& addTo(const Vector<T, size>& summand) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            this->data[i] += summand[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Vector<T, size>& subtractFrom(const Vector<T, size>& subtrahend) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            this->data[i] -= subtrahend[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename scalar>
    Vector<T, size>& multiplyBy(scalar factor) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] *= factor;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Vector<T, size>& multiplyBy(const Vector<T, size>& factor) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] *= factor[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename scalar>
    Vector<T, size>& divideBy(scalar divisor) {
        this->multiplyBy(1 / divisor);
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename otherT>
    Vector<T, size>& divideBy(const Vector<otherT, size>& divisor) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] /= divisor[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename dotResult>
    dotResult dotWith(const Vector<T, size>& other) const {
        dotResult help = dotResult(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            help += data[i] * other[i];
        }
        return help;
    }

    inline T dotWith(const Vector<T, size>& other) const {
        return this->dotWith<T>(other);
    }

    inline T length() const {
        return sqrt(this->lengthSquared());
    }

    T lengthSquared() const {
        T help = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            help += data[i] * data[i];
        }
        return help;
    }

    Vector<T, size>& normalize() {
        this->divide(this->length());
        return *this;
    }

    T angle(const Vector<T, size>& other) const {
        //Using normalized vectors minimizes rounding problems
        return acos(normalize(*this).dot(normalize(other)));
    }

    Vector<T, size> cross(const Vector<T, size>& other) {
        static_assert(size == 3, "Crossproduct is only defined for Vectors of size 3!");

        Vector<T, size> result;
        result[0] = data[1] * other[2] - data[2] * other[1];
        result[1] = data[2] * other[0] - data[0] * other[2];
        result[2] = data[0] * other[1] - data[1] * other[0];
        return result;
    }

public:
    template<typename scalar>
    static inline Vector<T, size> multiply(Vector<T, size> vector, scalar scalar) {
        return vector.multiplyBy(scalar);
    }

    template<typename scalar>
    static inline Vector<T, size> divide(Vector<T, size> vector, scalar scalar) {
        return vector.divideBy(scalar);
    }

    static inline Vector<T, size> multiply(Vector<T, size> first, const Vector<T, size>& second) {
        return first.multiplyBy(second);
    }

    static inline Vector<T, size> divide(Vector<T, size> first, const Vector<T, size>& second) {
        return first.divideBy(second);
    }

    static inline Vector<T, size> add(Vector<T, size> first, const Vector<T, size>& second) {
        return first.addTo(second);
    }

    static inline Vector<T, size> subtract(Vector<T, size> first, const Vector<T, size>& second) {
        return first.subtractFrom(second);
    }

    template<typename dotResult>
    static inline dotResult dot(Vector<T, size> first, const Vector<T, size>& second) {
        return first.dotWith(second);
    }

    static inline T dot(const Vector<T, size>& first, const Vector<T, size>& second) {
        return dot<T>(first, second);
    }

    static inline Vector<T, size> normalize(Vector<T, size> vector) {
        return vector.normalize();
    }

    static inline Vector<T, size> angle(const Vector<T, size>& first, const Vector<T, size>& second) {
        return first.angle(second);
    }

    static inline Vector<T, size> cross(const Vector<T, size>& first, const Vector<T, size>& second) {
        return first.cross(second);
    }

public:
    inline T& operator[](uint32_t i) {
        assert(i < size);
        return data[i];
    }
    inline T operator[](uint32_t i) const {
        assert(i < size);
        return data[i];
    }

    /*Vector addition*/
    inline Vector<T, size> operator+(const Vector<T, size> summand) const {
        return Vector<T, size>::add(*this, summand);
    }

    /*Vector subtraction*/
    inline Vector<T, size> operator-(const Vector<T, size> subtrahend) const {
        return Vector<T, size>::subtract(*this, subtrahend);
    }

    /*Dot product*/
    inline T operator*(const Vector<T, size> other) const {
        return Vector<T, size>::dot(*this, other);
    }

    /*Scalar multiplication*/
    template <typename scalar>
    inline Vector<T, size> operator*(const scalar& scalar) const {
        return Vector<T, size>::multiply(*this, scalar);
    }
    template <typename scalar>
    inline friend Vector<T, size> operator*(const scalar& scalar, const Vector<T, size>& vector) {
        return Vector<T, size>::multiply(*this, scalar);
    }

    /*Scalar division*/
    template <typename scalar>
    inline Vector<T, size> operator/(const scalar& scalar) const {
        return Vector<T, size>::divideBy(scalar);
    }
    template <typename scalar>
    inline friend Vector<scalar, size> operator/(const scalar& scalar, const Vector<T, size>& vector) {
        return Vector<scalar, size>(scalar).divideBy(vector);
    }

    inline Vector<T, size> operator-() const {
        return Vector<T, size>::multiply(*this, -1);
    }

    inline Vector<T, size> operator+() const {
        return *this;
    }

    inline Vector<T, size>& operator+=(const Vector<T, size>& summand) {
        this->addTo(summand);
    }

    inline Vector<T, size>& operator-=(const Vector<T, size>& subtrahend) {
        this->subtractFrom(subtrahend);
    }

    template<typename scalar>
    inline Vector<T, size>& operator*=(const scalar& factor) {
        this->multiplyBy(factor);
    }

    template<typename scalar>
    inline Vector<T, size>& operator/=(const scalar& divisor) {
        this->divideBy(divisor);
    }

    template <int newSize>
    operator Vector<T, newSize>() const {
        Vector<T, newSize> result;
        for (int i = 0; i < newSize; ++i) {
            result[i] = (i < size) ? data[i] : T(0);
        }
        return result;
    }

    inline bool operator==(const Vector<T, size>& other) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            if (data[i] != other[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    inline bool operator!=(const Vector<T, size>& other) {
        return !operator==(other);
    }
};

typedef Vector<float, 2> Vector2;
typedef Vector<float, 3> Vector3;
typedef Vector<float, 4> Vector4;
```

Comment: LukeG, I'm traveling right now and don't have it handy, Scott Meyer's Effective C++ item 44 covers a big code bloat issue that is related to passing a uint in with your template parameter.  Every time that Vector template is instantiated with a different size, it will be copied entirely in the source.  This could lead to huge execution binaries.  For what should be a trivial amount of code.  Google books has a snippet of this item in the preview, but I highly recommend it as a reference book as well.

Comment: I should add, that item 44 also covers a refactoring strategy for resolving that issue.

Comment: Most of your operations are mutating the *this and then returning it. You should really consider either mutation or returning the result, but not both at the same time.

Comment: @JamesFegan Just to comment on your point: I actually count on that behaviour, as I need constant size types for use with graphic API (should have mentioned that in the post).

Comment: @Caleth I'm returning as reference, this allows something like 'v1.addTo(v2).subtractFrom(v3)' which equals 'v1 + v2 - v3'. Do you think it's worthwile to do this or should I cancel this for performance reasons?

Comment: My point is e.g. (v1 + v2) * (v1 + v3) isn't defined as you have it. I also don't see the point of .AddTo being public when you have + overloads

Comment: @Caleth Just tested you example, works just as expected... I think you overlooked something, but I kinda get your second point.

Comment: what do you expect it to do? Specifically for `Vector<int, 1> v1, v2, v3, res; v1 = 1; v2 = 2; v3 = 3; res =  (v1 + v2) * (v1 + v3);` vs `int i1, i2, i3, res; i1 = 1; i2 = 2; i3 = 3; res = (i1 + i2) * (i1 + i3);`

Comment: @Caleth You do realize that the operator * is defined as the **dot product** and not as a element wise multiplication? So of course this does not work because the type of '(v1 + v2)*(v1 + v3)' is int instead of Vector<int, 1>

Comment: The usual way for matrix libraries to optimize temporaries is with expression templates. For example, for some matrices A and B, `A+b` doesn't actually do the addition and return a result--rather it returns an object containing references to the original objects plus an operator to add them on demand. As an expression is evaluated, a number of these are generated into some sort of tree. Then when the last one is assigned to the destination, all those are actually evaluated and a result is produced.

Comment: Jerry said better what I was getting at. I had meant element wise multiply, by that should be equal to doting 1Vectors anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take constant arguments by `const` reference, e.g.

   ```
   template<typename T, uint32_t size>
   Vector<T,N>::Vector(std::array<T, size> const&_data) : data(_data) {}
   template<typename T, uint32_t size>
   Vector<T,N>::Vector(T const&_datum) : data(_datum) {}
   ```

   also, you may want these constructors to be `explicit` (to disallow implicit usage as converting constructors).
2. Implement operations via `operator`s only. IMHO, there is not benefit in using the named functions. An implementation via expression templates is rather complicated and only really required in highly performance critical paths (when you may want to do things differently anyway).

   I don't think that the operation `scalar/Vector` should be supported. This is mathematically/syntactically wrong/dubious.
3. It makes sense to overload `abs(Vector const&vec)` to return `vec.length()`.
4. The cross product is best implemented as standalone function for 3D vectors only, avoiding the need for `static_assert`. You may also overload the `operator^` for this purpose (but consider operator preference).
5. You should follow the example of `std::vector` to provide memory access via `operator[]` w/o checking for out-of-bounds error and via member `at()` with out-of-bounds error. Don't merely assert, but `throw std::out_of_range`. (assert should only be used to check internally expected invariants, not user input.)
6. You may add some functionality to apply an arbitrary function to each element:

   ```
   template<typename T, uint32_t size>
   class Vector {

     template<typename Func>
     Vector& apply(Func const&func) noexcept(noexcept(func))
     {
       for(uint32_t i=0; i!=size; ++i)
         func(data[i]);
       return*this;
     }
   };
   ```

   You may also have similar methods for generating another `Vector` by element-wise operations ...
7. I would use `template` alias instead of your `typedef`s:

   ```
   template<typename T> using Vector2 = Vector<T,2>;
   ```